# webclient unable to download filename with '%' in it : 400 Bad Request Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to download files from a C# console application with `Webclient.DownloadFile()` method. I am easily able to download files named A-Za-z0-9. But when a filename has '%', it gives a 400 Bad Request.

Below is the code I use:

```
string filename = "a%bc.txt";
string remotePath = "https://exampleURL.com/Folder/"+filename;
striing localPath = @"F:\"+filename;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(remotePath), localPath);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

I tried `HTTPUtility.URLEncode()` but then it gave a 404 error. I referred a few blogs but none of them worked my way. Please help!

UPDATE:

Following are the exception details:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Please include your code that used `HttpUtility` (as a second code block). Also please confirm what URL you used from your web browser to **successfully** download the file. _Preferably not an example - the **actual** url._

Comment: Its a console app, I dont use web browser. Also, sorry I wont be able to post actual URL as it is official

Answer (score -1):

URLEncode will not escape a % in the string because % is a valid URL character.

Use

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(filename)
```

This will properly escape your filename for use in URI and should return: a%25bc.txt

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` also returns `a%25bc.txt` :)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not near an IDE so I can't test.  This will sound funny, make sure URI or the client isn't decoding it...try encoding it twice.  So it ends up as a%2525bc.txt